# iSpeech SDK with custom UI

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ispeech

I'm trying to use the iSpeech SDK(https://www.ispeech.org/developers/iphone) for my iPhone application for voice recognition. SDK is working fine. But I need to give my own UI and I will display their branding according to their branding guidelines.(https://www.ispeech.org/downloads/iSpeech%20Standard%20Usage%20Guidelines.pdf)

I'm using ISSpeechRecognition classe's - (BOOL)listen:(NSError **)err method. All the existing UI's are coming from the SDK. I need to change that.

Is above requirement possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the above requirement then you can contact iSpeech.org and they will give you a new SDK that you can customize those default behaviors. There you can hide those iSpeech specific dialog boxes etc.

Important : They will ask you questions about your applications. If your app is free, then they will distribute the new SDK for free. Otherwise I'm not sure. In my case they distributed  the SDK for free.

Comment: Great question and answer. Am experimenting with different options for voice recognition as well. What app did you make with this?

Comment: Please check this app. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-dubai-mall/id430795858?mt=8&ls=1

Got to HomePage->Car Parking. There you can save the car parking location using voice recognition. Let me know if you need any help.